# Different background-image by category

Tags: php, categories, css

I am trying to put different body background-image for each category.

```
body { 
background-color: #000; 
background-image: url(img/bg.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center top; 
font-size: 14px; color: #555; 
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; }
```

I only want different `background-image: url(img/bg.png);` for each catecory.

I found one possible method. It's like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /> 
<? php if( is_category(1) ) { ?> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<?php } 
elseif ( is_category (2) ) { ?> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<?php } 
elseif ( is_category (33) ) { ?> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <?php } 
else { ?> <?php } ?>
```

Still, I´m pretty sure it is not the best possible way to achieve my goal, because:

1) It looks for the whole stylesheet
2) It makes queries inside the header.php which might not be the best way considering page speed

My idea is to create different body classes:

```
body.apple { code here }
body.area { code here }
body.usa { code here }
body.bolt { code here }
body.jennifer { code here }
```

... or whatever.

I just need php to load different body classes from a single stylesheet for different categories.

Does anyone have a good solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using Wordpress's handy `body_class()` function. Depending on whether and how it is used in your theme, it may already be giving you what you need. Here's how to find out:

Check the source of your page to see if the `<body>` tag in your category archive pages has any classes containing your category slug: `category-apple`, `category-area`, `category-usa`, etc. These will typically be included by default.

- If they are there, you can use these as selectors in your CSS: `body.category-apple { /* code here */ }`, etc.
- If not, add the `body_class()` function to the `<body>` tag in your theme, probably located in header.php. It works like this:

  `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Optionally, you can add any extra class you want as a parameter.

Here's the entry in the Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Comment: Thaks @supertrue, it was really helpful. Beers on me mate ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is already built-in: the function `body_class()` creates special classes for each category:

**PHP**

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

**Output on category "jennifer"**

```
<body class="category-jennifer">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you theme is using [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) as it should be, then you already have all the classes you need.

For categories, you should have:

- category
- category-cat-name
- category-(id)
- category-paged-(page number)

If you have a lot of category rules, I'd suggest you conditionally load a stylesheet only for category archives. If you only have few rules it isn't worth it. Just include them in the main stylesheet.

```
function load_cat_style_wpse_87295() {
   if (!is_category()) return false;
   wp_register_style( 'catstyle', get_stylesheet_directory().'/path/to/stylesheet', false, null, 'all' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'catstyle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_cat_style_wpse_87295' );
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in other answers here, when you're on a category page, the `body_class` function already provides you with a class for the current category.

However, if you want the background-image to persist also in the category's posts, you can use the code provided by the [codex on the body_class function and filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class):

```
// add category nicenames in body class
function category_id_class($classes) {
   global $post;
   foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category)
        $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
   return $classes;
 }
 add_filter('body_class', 'category_id_class');
```